# Can you Desolder and replace RAM in Pi boards?

Tags: raspberry-pi, nanopi

Friendly Electronics has come out with a great small compact but very powerful board. It is called the Nano Pi fire 3. It has 8 cores which is great for programers like myself who want to utilize the cores for clusters and multiprocessing AI machines. However, it only has 1 GB of ram. Therefore, one of the processes I am trying to run can easily take up the ram of the entire board. It is fairly easy and straight forward to attach a cheap memory stick compatible with the board to allow for more swap space. This would be done so that the program can continue to run and not cause the board to entirely run out of memory. However, swap space is slow. Especially because the Nano Pi only allows for a USB 2.0, there is no real fast way to utilize the swap space. Unless I am wrong, then please correct and teach me how I would use the swap space in a faster manner. Now, assuming I am correct, the only way to truly speed up the board would be to actually give it a better physical RAM card. On a Raspberry Pi this is impossible/if you don't REALLY know what you are doing dumb. The reason I say this is because the Raspberry Pi places their RAM cards directly on top of the CPU's. I am not going to post the schematics of the Raspberry Pi, but you are welcome to look them up and fact check me. However, the Nano Pi and other boards from Friendly Electronics don't do this.

(here is the layout of the Nano Pi Fire 3):

[image: Nano Pi Schematics]

This image is from http://wiki.friendlyarm.com/wiki/index.php/NanoPi_Fire3

As you can see, the board has 1 GB of DDR3 RAM. It is easy and fairly inexpensive to buy a 16 GB chip of DDR3 RAM. Which is a very viable solution for myself and probably many people trying to get around their issues with slow boards. Is it possible to achieve what I want to do?

Comment: i would post this on electrical stack exchange

Comment: I am wondering how your process ends up taking up all the RAM. Assuming you're running a headless OS, it should consume a portion of that 1Gb and you should have plenty of memory available. It would probably be easier to optimize your program than try bold soldering experiments.